# Reference email template within template

Tags: magento2, email-templates

I am attempting to reference a newly created custom template via the admin panel within another email template. The template I am trying to access is called '`footer`' when I change the standard line to '`{{template config_path="design/email/footer"}}'` it gives me errors. Any assistance in getting this to work would be great.
Thanks